# Joomla - Making Custom HTML modules multilingual

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a Custom HTML module that displays information in one language for now, but I want to make it multilingual. I don't want to recreate the same module in 6 different languages, so is there a way have 1 single module with language constants?

I've tried looking up Language Overrides, but that wouldn't work in this situation because the module will strip out all PHP. Not to mention, I don't know where to even put the language constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. First you need to download the Sourcerer plugin. This enables you to use PHP within articles, modules, etc. Next, you go to `templates/your_template/html/modules.php` and change the line that displays the title. There might be several and each template is different, but this is how mine looked.

```
<?php if ($module->showtitle != 0) : ?>
<div class="module-title">
    <h2 class="title"><?php echo $module->title; ?></h2>
</div>
```

Change `$module->title` to `JText::_($module->title);`

Afterwards, go to the module and change the title to a language constant (ex. SEARCH_SITE). For the custom output, you have to put the following:

```
{source}<?php echo JText::_('SOMETHING_DESCRIPTIVE');?>{/source}
```

Then you go to Language Manager and add in the language constants for each language.

The only con for this technique is you will lose the `modules.php` change whenever you upgrade Joomla. Otherwise, it's a good solution for treating Custom HTML modules like a custom extension.